# How to check if a href element find in geb

Tags: testing, groovy, geb

I try to click html css 'a' but I cant access to it. How can I to do?

at test

```
waitFor { myelement.displayed }
myelement.click()

class test extends Page {

    static at = { title == "test page" }
    static content = {
        myelement {$("a", id: "myid")}
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! :-) It would be helpful to edit your question and also post the corresponding HTML code plus the error message you are getting incl. callstack. "Can't access it" hardly qualifies as a good problem description. Furthermore, I advise you to learn how to ask good questions by reading about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it directly using the ID. I think your syntax is incorrect, try using the ID selector instead: `$("#myId")`